# How to use datelist in a custom field widget?

Tags: entities, 9

Since an administrator of the website I am building is visually impaired, I need to create a custom date field widget rather than use the one provided by Drupal.

I am trying to implement a `datelist` element.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget;

use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\WidgetBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Accessible date field widget.
 *
 * @FieldWidget(
 *   id = "accessible_date",
 *   label = @Translation("Accessible date widget"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "datetime"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class AccessibleDate extends WidgetBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $max_year = date('Y') + 1;
    $default_date = new DrupalDateTime();
    if (isset($items[$delta]->value)) {
      $default_date = new DrupalDateTime($items[$delta]->value);
    }

    $element += [
      '#type' => 'datelist',
      '#default_value' => $default_date,
      '#date_part_order' => [
        'day',
        'month',
        'year',
        'hour',
        'minute',
      ],
      '#date_year_range' => '2000:' . $max_year,
    ];

    return ['value' => $element];
  }

}
```

The widget is displayed correctly but when I submit the form to add or edit a node, I have the following error on each of the datelist fields: "The datetime value must be a string."

[image]

Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, the datetime format needs a `Y-m-dTH:i:s` format.
I added a validate callback to my element to alter the data.

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $max_year = date('Y') + 1;
    dpm($items[$delta]->value);
    $default_date = new DrupalDateTime();
    if (isset($items[$delta]->value)) {
      $default_date = new DrupalDateTime($items[$delta]->value);
    }

    $element += [
      '#type' => 'datelist',
      '#default_value' => $default_date,
      '#date_part_order' => [
        'day',
        'month',
        'year',
        'hour',
        'minute',
      ],
      '#date_year_range' => '2000:' . $max_year,
      '#element_validate' => [
        [static::class, 'validate'],
      ],
    ];

    return ['value' => $element];
  }

  /**
   * Prepare datelist value.
   */
  public static function validate($element, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $value = $element['#value'];
    $date = $value['year'] . '-' . $value['month'] . '-' . $value['day'] . 'T' . $value['hour'] . ':' . $value['minute'] . ':00';
    $form_state->setValueForElement($element, $date);
  }
```